# Fetched data is not populated in table [vue]

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, vue.js, datatable

I am new to js/vue and I am trying to fetch data from an API. I have a field which value will be used to fetch data from the API for that keyword. I can see in the console log that I do get the data as an array. However, that data does not get populated in the table.

The odd thing that is worth mentioning is that if I make a slight change in the code, such as delete extra space and save...while I still have the browser open with the data fetched, then the table will get populated.

In the script I have:

```
let data;

const fetchData = async (inputString: string) => {
 data = await getData(inputString);
 console.log('Data', data);
 return data;
}
```

And the input field + button:
`<input v-model='inputString' placeholder='Write keyword here' /> <button action @click='fetchData(inputString)"> Fetch data </button>`

Answer (score 2):

Your data variable needs to be reactive for the template to know about changes.

```
import { ref } from 'vue';  
const data = ref<null|string>(null);

const fetchData = async (inputString: string) => {
 data.value = await getData(inputString);
 console.log('Data', data);
 return data.value;
}
```

In your template you can then simply use data like this:

```
<div>{{data}}</div>
```

See more about reactivity here: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#reactive-variables-with-ref

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I have tried your suggestion and I was unable to make it work. I also tried:

`import { ref } from "vue";

let data = ref();`

Also added let data = await getData

And added :ref="(data)" to the table. I think that you are absolutely correct that I need to make the variable reactive, I am just having hard time grasping the idea

Comment: I extended my answer a bit. You might be misssing the .value